# Помогите составить план действий для решения тестового задания OracleDB+Apex

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-apex

Суть задания сделать интеграцию с любым публичным web api (например яндекс погода).
Oracle Database для хранения данных, APEX или Tomcat+java сервлет для веб формы.
Система должна предоставлять WEB-обертку для обращения к api, логировать и хранить данные в нашей базе.

Вопрос  подскажите хорошие руководства с по построению подобных систем.
Стек мне не знакомый, знаю хорошо mssql, pascal.  java на начальном уровне.
Что быстрее приведет к успеху java сервлет и хостинг на tomcat или реализовать все силами oracle?

Comment: Возможно, человек, знающий java-фреймворки, скажет, что проще на java. Я знаю апекс и недавно начал по чуть-чуть изучать Spring Boot, поэтому мне кажется, что проще на апексе. Если время терпит, попробуйте по паре дней повозиться с обоими, позадавайте конкретные вопросы, а потом решите.

Comment: Для апекса можно взять готовый [плагин](https://github.com/jeffreykemp/jk64-plugin-simplemap) для работы с гуглокартами, расковырять его (весь код открыт) и сделать такой же.